# Kubuntu 18.04 - Application Launcher - Not opening when apps are open on the desktop

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, launcher

Long-time DOS/Windows user, but Linux noob here.

I have searched far and wide for an exact match for this issue, but haven't been able to turn up much info.

The issue I am having is that I cannot get the Application Launcher to open when I have application windows open on the desktop.  It does not matter whether they are full screen or windowed - so long as I have even one application visible on the desktop, the Application Launcher will not open by any method.

If I minimise the visible app windows, the application launcher will open just fine.

I have tried switching between Auto-hide and always visible for the application bar, but that makes no difference.

The build is a fresh installation of 18.04 (i.e.: I blew away my 16.04 installation and installed 18.04 from scratch); however, the Application Launcher on my 16.04 installation never had a problem.

Any ideas on what's causing the issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Seems to be caused by Window Focus Behavior. This can be searched for or found in Window Behavior in System Settings for KDE. Lowering or disabling the setting for "Focus Stealing Prevention" seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey Average Joesson! Please make sure that your answer is detailed.

Comment: @technastic_tc My answer is as detailed as I understand the problem. Typing in "Window Focus Behavior" in the application launcher will find you the window you need to edit. There's a setting there called "Focus Stealing Prevention". The setting has a drop down menu which you can select None through Extreme. If it's Extreme, then Focus Stealing Prevention is so preventative that you can't select the application launcher, if it's set to None, then you should be able to select the application launcher even when another window is maximized.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer and add these details. It'll be helpful for the community.